# Accessing Buffers in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

So I am aware that you can generate buffers using:

```
GLuint Buffer = 0;
glGenBuffers (1, &Buffer);
```

I am told that this will generate 1 buffer in the address of `Buffer`. I am also told that if I do this:

```
GLuint Buffer = 0;
glGenBuffers (2, &Buffer);
```

Then it will generate 2 buffers in the address of `Buffer`. So how do I access this 2nd buffer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass an array/vector to `glGenBuffers`, for example as follows:

```
std::vector<GLuint> buffers(2); //or std::array<GLuint, 2> buffers;
glGenBuffers(2, &buffers[0]); 
...
// Access buffer elements at buffers[0] and buffers[1]
...
glDeleteBuffers(2, &buffers[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

While some people consider plain arrays to be obsolete in C++ (and I don't mean to start a holy war), it's worth pointing out that this also works without using any C++ containers. An old style array will work just fine:

```
GLuint buffers[2];
glGenBuffers(2, buffers);
```

Then use `buffers[0]` and `buffers[1]` to reference the two buffer names you generated.